# Minimizing large queries before passing them to Solr

Tags: solr, boolean-expression, minimize, heuristics, karnaugh-map

I'm working on a problem to minimize large boolean expressions that are being provided as the input to Solr. 
This seems like a problem similar to minimizing the logic gates on a circuit by using techniques like boolean algebra / K-Map. However, these techniques are useful for smaller expressions but not if the expressions is very big. 
What other approaches/ algorithms to could be used for solving this problem?

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve (by just looking at single inputs being booleans) is NP-complete - so any optimization will be bounded by that, or simplified based on your actual problem. Do you have an example of what you're trying to simplify, and why it's more efficient to do that yourself instead of letting Lucene (which has more information about what's going on behind the scenes) optimize the query?

Comment: @MatsLindh the problem that I've been is to reduce the complexity/ size of the expressions that are being passed to solr. For Example, consider this case:
(id  NOT IN (1, 2,3, ... 1000) AND id IN (1,2,3,...,1001)) - this just leaves 1001 and no need to evaluate from 1 to 1000. I think Lucene will try and evaluate all the conditions and may not be smart enough to just evaluate for 1001.
I am currently evaluating Quine-McCluskey algorithm but not sure if that's the best way to go about it. The expression can have thousands of variables.

Comment: If your terms are of the same type as you gave in your example, you probably want to look at set theory instead of boolean logic to make this performant. In the case above you have two sets, and you want to get the set that matches the difference between them. This also maps neatly to ranges if necessary. This is also how Lucene works internally (with sets and the intersection between them), but I'm not familiar enough with the code to say anything definite about your example - but my guess is that you're right.

Comment: @MatsLinth it's not about just that example, there could be several conditions like this. Another eg: (Color = YELLOW && Category= Clothing) || Color=YELLOW || Category =Clothing. There could be thousands of conditions like this all with different or same variables. In fact, Quine-McCluskey might not even prove to be reliable here with the increasing number of inputs, ll have to look at heuristic approaches as well.